# I need a windows client for vless, vmess which supports firewall

Tags: windows, vpn, proxy, tunnel

I want to connect to the VMess protocol, and block all of the non-vpn traffics.

I try [V2rayN](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayN) and [Nekoray](https://github.com/MatsuriDayo/nekoray), both proxy mode and TUN/VPN mode, but still can't block non-vpn traffic and one of the my apps, detects my real ip.

I want something like [Firewall feature](https://windscribe.com/features/firewall#:%7E:text=It%20blocks%20all%20connectivity%20outside,leaks%2C%20WebRTC%20leaks%2C%20etc.) in Windscribe app:

[image]

When I enable this feature with Windscribe, all of the my apps including that one detect VPN IP as my IP, but if I use V2rayN or Nekoray, some apps detects my real IP.

Is there any other clients for VMess protocol that supports this feature?

Or can I implement this feature in V2rayN or Nekoray app?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

"[Clash For Windows](https://www.clashforwindows.net/)" has so many different settings for any kind of rules that you may need. You can run CFW in proxy mode or TUN mode. You can set rules for destinations based on domain name, IP address, top-level domain (like .ir or .cn), or even your custom regex patterns. You can set a "kill switch" for different situations, or you can share your proxied internet over your LAN. Alternatively, you may want to use multiple configs at the same time! For example, you can use CFW to connect your PC to Germany but use Turkey's IP for Netflix, Switzerland's IP for Spotify, Finland's IP for Binance, and have a direct connection to governmental websites and apps.

You can do many things with CFW, but it's a bit tricky and hard to learn due to the lack of proper documentation. You may need to spend a couple of days to figure out how to configure CFW properly.

I must also add that, unfortunately, "Clash For Windows" doesn't support vless or reality (yet), if that's important to you. It only supports Trojan, VMess, Shadowsocks, Socks5, HTTP/HTTPS, and Snell protocols. You may need some useful websites like [this](https://v2rayse.com/en/clash-convert/) or [this](https://sshkit.com/subconverter/) to create your first CFW config file based on your current configurations.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).